# How to determine whether a Swift code is running inside XCode Playground

Tags: swift

I'm writing a simple application reading CSV file in Swift and I would like to be able to use the same code in Playground and as an input file to the `swift` command.

To read a file in Playground I have to use this code

```
let filePath = XCPlaygroundSharedDataDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data.csv")
```

I would like to achieve something like:

```
#if PLAYGROUND
import XCPlayground
let filePath = XCPlaygroundSharedDataDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data.csv")
#else
let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("data.csv")
#endif
```

Comment: I think you can use the bundle identifier to determine you're running in the playground - as I recall it's something like `com.apple.?.playground`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test is quite simple:

```
let bundleId = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier ?? ""
if bundleId.hasPrefix("com.apple.dt"){
        //... Your code
}
```

But I think you have already seen the problem once you've done that... the import will stop the build elsewhere. I suspect you are trying to build a playground for a framework you have built (if not, I'm not quite sure how the code is being shared)... The way I solved it in the framework was to provide an optional call back hook for the value I wanted to get... so for example

**In Framework**

```
public defaultUrlHook : (()->NSURL)? = nil

internal var defaultUrl : NSURL {
    return defaultUrlHook?() ?? NSURL.fileURLWithPath("data.csv")
}
```

**In playground**

```
import XCPlayground
import YourFramework

defaultUrlHook = { ()->NSURL in 
      return XCPlaygroundSharedDataDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data.csv")
}

//Do your thing....
```